# How to hide a certain entry in a row from repeating recordset

Tags: php, html

Hi i have a repeating recordset, in which i want to hide some entry(html div) in a row as required.
my database has a table with 7 columns, now i have a condition when i dont wont to display a entry(element) in a row.

to explain further please look at my html code block.

```
<?php do { ?>
<div class="category-container">
<div class="category-image"><?php echo $list['image']?></div>    
<div class="category-desc"> <a href="<?php echo $list['titlelink']?>"><?php echo $list['title']?></a>
<p><?php echo $list['description']?></p></div>       
<div class="rating<?php echo $list['rating']?>" >Editors' rating: </div>    
<div class="category-download-btn"><a href="<?php echo $list['download']?>">&raquo; Download &raquo;</a></div>    
<div class="category-buy-btn"><a href="<?php echo $list['buy']?>">&laquo; Buy &laquo;</a></div>    
</div> <?php } while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2)); ?>
```

i have a div (`"class=category-buy-btn"`) which i want to hide in case when there is no buy link, i have set it fetch url from database.

A simple approach to do this that come to me is making a new column 'buydiv' and putting the entire div in this column 'buydiv' and not to put value in row which i dont want to show, like this.

```
<?php echo $list['buydiv']?>
```

in place of

```
<div class="category-buy-btn"><a href="<?php echo $list['buy']?>">&laquo; Buy &laquo;</a></div>
```

content of `$list['buydiv']` will then have these values.

```
<div class="category-buy-btn"><a href="<?php echo $list['buy']?>">&laquo; Buy &laquo;</a></div>
```

Now this is really not a good aproach to do it, can someone please suggest me any better way to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make it conditional on `$list['buy']` being non-empty:

```
<?php if (!empty($list['buy'])) : ?>
<div class="category-buy-btn"><a href="<?php echo $list['buy']?>">&laquo; Buy &laquo;</a></div>    
<?php endif ?>
```

---

**Update**: In order to make sure your UTF-8 strings are displayed correctly, you need to tell the browser to interpret the page as UTF-8:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
```

and make sure your SQL queries are being run as UTF-8:

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
```

See [this](http://www.klopfenstein.net/lorenz.aspx/php-mysql-and-utf-encoding) for more info, and see [this](http://www.phpwact.org/php/i18n/charsets) for a more exhaustive guide to Unicode in PHP. It's potentially quite a confusing topic, so it's worth reading about. This is also very instructive reading:

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: its working, thanks a lot man you are awesome, i didn't know it can be done like this.

Comment: also can you suggest me which mysql collation method should i choose for my database i have choosen UTF-8 Unicode (utf8).

Comment: @TallboY Yes, that's a sensible option. There are a couple of things to be aware of, however; see my update.